# Samsung galaxy s2 bootloader

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I was trying to install the Ubuntu touch into my Samsung galaxy s2 .. when I entered at the terminal 'adb reboot bootloader' the mobile rebooted but didn't enter the boot loader !! any help please? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hold the volume-down button, the Home button and power button until the phone restarts and don't let go, the bootloader should appear after 10 seconds approx.